# Can someone please explain to me why sorting function returns "None"

Tags: python

```
numbers = input("Enter numbers.")

numbersArray = numbers.split()

realNumbersArray = []



for x in numbersArray:
 realNumbersArray.append(int(x))
 print(x)
 
print(len(realNumbersArray))

print(realNumbersArray.sort())
```

Can someone explain why the second print command keeps returning "None"?

Comment: `.sort()` returns None because _that's how it works_.  It sorts the actual list; it does not return a _new_ sorted list.  Why were you expecting something else?  Did you read the documentation?

Comment: Calm down.  I didn't read "the documentation", I read it was an array method on W3schools.  I've been coding for years and never run into a problem like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76486353/4245744), if you want to output a sorted version of the array but you *don't* want to alter the original array, you can do:

```
print(len(realNumbersArray))
print(sorted(realNumbersArray))
print(realNumbersArray)
```

The important concept here is that what a function/method *does* and what it *returns* often aren't the same thing. The `.sort()` is designed for cases where you want to sort an array/etc. but don't immediately want to look at the sorted values; functions of that kind will often return None. `sorted()` is for cases where you want to create a sorted version, and do something with it immediately, *without* changing the original.

Answer (score 2):

the `.sort()` sorts the array in place but returns `None`. your `realNumbersArray` is now sorted and if you print it, you will see the list sorted as expected.

You want to do this:

```
print(len(realNumbersArray))
realNumbersArray.sort()    # Array is now sorted
print(realNumbersArray)    # Print sorted array
```

Comment: See examples here: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html